# SQL Update Query Error in PHP Function

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm currently trying to use the following PHP function/SQL query with a page that edits medications on a project I'm building for school. I'm getting the following error and having trouble to finding where the error is :

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

```
function edit_medicine($medicine_name, $medicine_dose, $medicine_date, $medicine_current, $medicine_id) {
global $db;
$query = "UPDATE Medicine
             SET MedicineName = :medicine_name, 
             Medicine Dose = :medicine_dose, 
             MedicineDatePrescribed = :medicine_date, 
             MedicineCurrent = :medicine_current
              WHERE MedicineKey = :medicine_id";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':medicine_name', $medicine_name);
$statement->bindValue(':medicine_dose', $medicine_dose);
$statement->bindValue(':medicine_date', $medicine_date);
$statement->bindValue(':medicine_current', $medicine_current);
$statement->bindValue(':medicine_id', $medicine_id);
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
}
```

I'd appreciate any help anyone can offer- it's the end of finals week and I'm totally burnt out. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your honesty

Comment: ``Medicine Dose` , not 'Medicine Dose', please refer to Logan s answer

Answer (score 4):

Use quote to your column names, especially your `Medicine Dose` column because of its space (). Next time, don't use space to name your columns:

```
$query = "UPDATE `Medicine`
             SET `MedicineName` = :medicine_name, 
             `Medicine Dose` = :medicine_dose, 
             `MedicineDatePrescribed` = :medicine_date, 
             `MedicineCurrent` = :medicine_current
             WHERE `MedicineKey` = :medicine_id";
```

Comment: Thanks! However, that didn't fix my query. I appreciate your answer, though.  I'm still getting "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''MedicineName' = 'Topamax', 'Medicine Dose' = '20 mg', ' at line 2' "

Comment: You need to alter table and change column name to something like `MedicineDose` or `Medicine_Dose`

Comment: @SarahB - are you sure you used backticks (`), not apostrophe/single tick ('). Because they are different to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If double quotes or backtick does not work , try including the string within square brackets.

For example

`SELECT [Business Name],[Other Name] FROM your_Table`